# Mecha anime with giant robots summoned from sky, water and earth

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can't remember the name of this anime I watched when I was child.

It was a little bit old, a mecha anime probably from 90’s. In it there are 3 boys who have gigantic robots. One boy summons his robot from the sky by using a bow. One boy who has rabbit ears summons his robot from the water, and the main role boy summons his robot from the earth.

Comment: This story-identification question is about an anime that features "gigantic robots", which sounds like science fiction. Hence, I have migrated it here.

Comment: This question could use a better title and more details.

Comment: @Allball103 - You can use the [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/177073/edit) button to fix the title yourself

Answer (score 12):

It looks like this is [Madö King Granzört](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad%C3%B6_King_Granz%C3%B6rt).

> mecha anime probably from 90’s

According to the wikipedia page, this aired in NTV from April 7, 1989 to March 2, 1990.

The hero of our story here is a boy called Daichi, who

> arrives on the Moon and hears the strange stories about people with rabbit ears...

He soon learns that he is a chosen warrior who

> will save the Long-Ears race and their land Rabiluna from the evil Jadou Clan. With the magic gun, Daichi can summon Granzort – the Madou King of Earth – a giant robot.

There are also two other characters who summon robots in the way you described:

> two other boys – Gus and Rabi. Gus receives a magic bow that summons Winzart – the Madou King of Wind, while Rabi receives a magic top that summons Aquabeat – the Madou King of Water.